# using Leaflet.TextPath in R

Tags: r, leaflet, polyline, r-leaflet

I would like to plot a `Polyline` using R's `leaflet` package. This `Polyline` is supposed to have arrows alongside the line to illustrate that the `Polyline` has a time dimension.

There's a [plugin for `leaflet.js`](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) that implements this feature by printing arrow heads as text along the `Polyline` (in fact [there's also another, similar one](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator)) but I am at a loss as to how I would integrate this plugin with the R package.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/8f6c8cc27597466351ad377e6774c30f may be of use